# In TypeScript, how can I narrow a type through a series of filters?

Tags: typescript, typeguards, narrowing

I want to apply a chain of filters to an array and narrow the type accordingly. The array elements belong to a union type with some shared properties.

```
type TypeA = {name: string; id: string; createdAt: Date};
type TypeB = {name: string; id: string; metaData: Record<string, unknown>};
type TypeC = {id: string};
type TypeD = {name: string; createdAt: Date};
// etc.

type MyUnionType = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC | TypeD;

const hasName = (x: MyUnionType): x is MyUnionType & {name: string} => 'name' in x;
const hasId = (x: MyUnionType): x is MyUnionType & {id: string} => 'id' in x;

function foo(ary: MyUnionType[]) {
    ary.filter(hasName)
       .filter(hasId)
       .map(x => x.name + x.id);  // ❌ Error because it thinks property `id` does not exist
}
```

I've thought of two workarounds:

1. Write a specific filter for the combination I need:

```
function hasNameAndId(x: MyUnionType): x is MyUnionType & {name: string} {
    return 'name' in x && 'id' in x;
}
```

This solution isn't scalable, as it means writing a function for each combination of filters.

2. Instead of using named filter functions, write the filters inline with the type information:

```
function foo(ary: MyUnionType[]) {
    ary.filter((x): x is MyUnionType & {name: string} => 'name' in x)
       .filter((x: MyUnionType & {name: string}): x is MyUnionType & {name: string; id: string} => 'id' in x)
       .map(x => x.name + x.id);
}
```

This solution gets messy very quickly.

Comment: Thanks.  [Here](https://tsplay.dev/WJrgRW) is the approach I'd take, making the type guard functions generic.  Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Amazing! That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call [type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) directly, the compiler performs the sort of narrowing you're looking for automatically:

```
function foo(ary: MyUnionType[]) {
  ary.flatMap(x => hasName(x) && hasId(x) ? x.name + x.id : []) 
}
```

But in order for [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to work as a type guard function you need to pass in a callback that exactly matches the [relevant call signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/80ab111685e3e0c10d8d13cdd18d8dffa8328895/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1444C1-L1444C88):

```
interface Array<T> {
  map<U>(cb: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => U, thisArg?: any): U[];
}
```

And unfortunately that's not what's happening after you call `ary.filter(hasName).filter(hasId)`, where the array element is of type `MyUnionType & { name: string }`, but your callback takes an argument of type `MyUnionType`.  Those aren't seen as compatible enough, so the type guard is skipped and you just get the "normal" `filter()` behavior where the output type doesn't change.

---

The most straightforward way around this, I think, is to make your type guard functions [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) so that the call to the second `filter()` can instantiate the generic type parameter accordingly.  Something like this:

```
const hasName = <T extends MyUnionType>(x: T): x is T & { name: string } => 'name' in x;
const hasId = <T extends MyUnionType>(x: T): x is T & { id: string } => 'id' in x;
```

And then the second `filter()` call works; `T` will be instantiated with `MyUnionType & {name: string}`, and the return type is an array of `(MyUnionType & {name: string}) & {id: string})`, as desired:

```
function foo(ary: MyUnionType[]) {
  ary.filter(hasName)
    .filter(hasId)
    .map(x => x.name + x.id); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#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-gCaSCwZqY3GYXDUMnDrmMfBM-j+a25AWYp8yRSqYxK3TNYzMMzWezOdKU8cuxARWLI8bpbL5bwGmaLWW6wnLmLnq8obD91AAPwOm32q1MKBERean2SscTjpQABGXJ5s7TQtF4pXHkdUVCBlVVNQjWNbU5RAsCDUYSDjWqU1zQeHcrSvB0nWkSUfW9IA)